# Behat functional test stop Symfony HttpKernal redirects

Tags: rest, functional-testing, behat, symfony5

I'm using Behat to test a REST API my team has developed.  When a particular resource is created the API returns a 201 and a Location header in the response.

The API was developed using using Symfony5 and it's using the Symfony HttpKernel as the client:

```
$kernel->handle($request);
```

I would like to assert through my behat test that it returns a 201 and the headers contains the Location.  However the client is automatically following the Location header and as such I can't verify that.

Is there a way to turn off following redirects using the existing kernel component?  I've not been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own context and check the Response

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Features\Context;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

final class HttpContext
{
    private Kernel $kernel;
    private Response $response;

    public function __construct(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @When I request :method to :uri
     */
    public function iRequest(string $method, string $uri): void
    {
        $this->request($method, $uri);
    }

    /**
     * @Then the location header should be :location
     */
    public function assertLocationHeader(string $location): void
    {
        // make your assertion
        dd($this->response->headers->get('location'), $location);
    }

    private function request(string $method, string $uri): void
    {
        $request = Request::create($uri, $method, [], [], [], [], null);

        $this->response = $this->kernel->handle($request);

        $this->kernel->terminate($request, $this->response);
    }
}
```